# Inferring return type from generic type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

The following works but `.getData()` has a return type of `any` which isn't ideal as this is a consumer face API call.

In reality the return type here isn't `any`thing, but is strictly dependant on the type of object held in the items array.

Is there anyway I can provide a return type to consumer of this method?

```
class Group<T> {
  items: Array<T> = [];

  addItem(item: T) {
      this.items.push(item);
  }

  getData(itemIndex: number) {
    // Any is T
    return (this.items[itemIndex] as any).data;
  }
}

class NumberItem {
  data: number;

  constructor(data: number) {
      this.data = data;
  }
}

class StringItem {
  data: String = "";

  constructor(data: String) {
      this.data = data;
  }
}

let n1 = new NumberItem(3);
let n2 = new NumberItem(4);

let g1 = new Group<NumberItem>();
g1.addItem(n1);
g1.addItem(n2);

console.log(g1.getData(1));
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDiBOB7ArgBwDwBUB80DeAsAFDTQCWALgKYC2EAXNAILzxgCeWuAvNANoBdANzFipMABMJASWo0AFJVqNMASnxjSWigAsyEAHRK6B1Mgg7Fc1SJLQAvqLsBzKhQAiYCmCu1pAOwkqAA9Gf2QaACMqeHVCO1IAekTmf3ZyGExNUng3ZHh-aHldfSM5CD5jAKDggWhIerTVAwkvMFtSRyIu4lBIGAA5COj4WVoNO1bvMOGY201gRH8ICnhkYApEeHkpsBmomLjs7T1DXeheXY6HYh6iPqhoAGVVsn9nMZoJ0l3GF-g3s4LtAAEQg+Z2RbLVbrTbbX7PV7vI4JE6lc6XNrXLp3EBuaD+ACMwP8VAA7tAhgdRnJ5ABmGzEPEUAkAJhJ5MpsxptHkABZGUQmfjnMTeKSKQgUBgqSNPth5ILRQZJDJaUSlYSVVJPvJ-KzBb0lhBEHiDCBEM55MrXB42vJCapDUQgA)

Comment: How do you expect it to be able to infer the type from a property thats inside a generic type? You should be using `unknown`, but thats about as good as it gets.

Comment: @MikeS. That is wrong; see my answer.

Comment: @kaya3 It's not wrong but I worded it incorrectly. You cannot know the type from a property inside of a generic, if you do not know the property name, Your solution works because it relies on the `data` property to always be there. Neat solution though, didn't know you can do this.

Comment: @MikeS. This question doesn't involve the case where the property name is unknown, but in that case it's *still* possible; the upper bound would not be required, and the return type would be `T[keyof T]`.

Comment: You are absolutely right, thank you for clarifying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `T` an upper bound so that it has a `data` property, then the return type is `T['data']`. This way there is also no need for a type assertion inside the `getData` method.

```
class Group<T extends { data: any }> {
  items: Array<T> = [];

  addItem(item: T) {
    this.items.push(item);
  }

  getData(itemIndex: number): T['data'] {
    return this.items[itemIndex].data;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
let n1 = new NumberItem(3);
let n2 = new NumberItem(4);

let g1 = new Group<NumberItem>();
g1.addItem(n1);
g1.addItem(n2);

// result: number
const result = g1.getData(1);
```

Comment: I've updated my code, still shows any as the type
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDiBOB7ArgBwDwBVoFMAeALjgHYAmMA3tKWAWAFzRjECe0AvgHzQUCwAUNGgBLIgFsIjAILx4YFlm4BeaAG0AugG4BAoWFKkAkuIAUonGMaYAlD11CHBABbCIAOnMS3qZBCdnxa21BDh0QgHMcAgARWjAAi0MyfEZiZDEAIxx4Wz4QoQB6AugpVhEYTHsheCjkeGJoZ1cPcQhVTyTSfHU3GjpgoXYBIf4BUEgYADl0rPhjCzsQvoZoNMzs4PtgRGIIAnhkYAJEeBNl1Jns3KrHF3dl6BVlgdD+EbHwKGgAZX3hYnC8zEiyE5x+fwBj2gACJoZsQttdvtDsdTmDfvB-uFrvlbs0Hk84i8Ru9+CAoqsAIxQ4g4ADu0Gm6zmpgAzEEBOSCKsAEw0+mMy4siwmAAsHNGZIp4WpKlpDIQKAwTNmQM4JglMrc+iMpmIlM1lO1BiBJmIPIlnIpBOgWsiMTiJgN8MREEQ5LcIEQ4TOcUt-CAA

Comment: @user11406 You didn't add the return type annotation `: T['data']`.

Comment: Super neat! I had no idea this was possible. Thank you.